# Why do I loose ping after adding static route

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

Since I live in one of the countries with most freedom ever been presented to citizens, I'm using a VPN all the time to connect to free world. Well, this way my connection gets slower but as I grow older and older behind my desktop, I can surf the net.

But I ssh into our company server almost all the time and it does not need to go through VPN so I'm trying to handle this with a static route. **I want all the traffic to go through the VPN except for a single IP address.**

I try it like this:

```
$ sudo ip route add x.x.x.x dev wlan0
```

But after that, I no longer can ping the server:

```
$ ping x.x.x.x                          
PING x.x.x.x 56(84) bytes of data.
From SAM-ThinkPad-E450 (192.168.1.103) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From SAM-ThinkPad-E450 (192.168.1.103) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From SAM-ThinkPad-E450 (192.168.1.103) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: You also need to instruct the OS how to reach the IP range. i.e. which gateway to use.
Something like the below should work :
`sudo ip route add <IPRange> via  <Gateway> dev wlan0`

Comment: @MidwayNomad How can I set it to be the gateway for wlan0 without specifying static IP?

Comment: The command instructs your OS to use the gateway to reach the specific IP range.

Comment: @MidwayNomad I know, but if as I'm using dhcp an static IP address may not work all the time.

Comment: but wouldnt the default gateway have a static ip? and can you not use this to get to the office server?

Comment: @MidwayNomad So I need to modify the rule every time the gw ip changes?

Comment: right, you are correct.

Comment: Hi @Mehraban, I was reading through Arch wiki and came across this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd, please look at 'DHCP static route(s)'. Does this help?

Comment: @MidwayNomad The example contains two fully specified subnets. I was looking for a way to get gateway address dynamically (via dhcp maybe). So the answer is no, it does not help.